# Placing a tilted rectangle behind image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do this in css and html:

[image]

What I got so far:

```
<div id="logo-container">
  <img decoding="async" src="https://articlett.de/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/elementor/thumbs/Articlett_Logo_RGB_1100x245px_2021-09-18_RZ_black-q1r7rix22o6ztvjf52cf1pt1ojwen0jx1zyxtcyq8m.png" title="Articlett_Logo_RGB_1100x245px_2021-09-18_RZ_black" alt="Articlett_Logo_RGB_1100x245px_2021-09-18_RZ_black" loading="lazy"> 
  <div id="logo-shadow">
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#logo-shadow {
  width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    transform: skew(20deg);
    position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px; 
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: -1;
 }

#logo-container {
    position: relative;    
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hobqmxjp/

[image]

Despite not knowing how to get the right shape with css, the problem is, that I need the background rectangle to have the width according to the logo file and not a fix width/height. So it also works responsive.

How can I achieve these two things?

Also

Comment: Why don't you just make a svg out of the file, so you don't need to worry?

Comment: Make the container inline-block (or add an additional container wrapping image and shadow), so that its width will be that of the image. And then simply don't specify a width for your absolutely positioned show, but a `right` "coordinate" as well. (And the extra shadow div could of course be replaced by a pseudo element of the container to begin with.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will scale with the image. I have changed `skew` to `rotate` as I think this is more likely to give the desired look.

```css
#logo-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; /* space of text including padding */
  height: 55%; /* desired height */
  transform: rotate(-2deg); /* rotation of the rectangle */
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: -1;
}

#logo-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo-container">
  <img decoding="async" src="https://articlett.de/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/elementor/thumbs/Articlett_Logo_RGB_1100x245px_2021-09-18_RZ_black-q1r7rix22o6ztvjf52cf1pt1ojwen0jx1zyxtcyq8m.png" title="Articlett_Logo_RGB_1100x245px_2021-09-18_RZ_black" alt="Articlett_Logo_RGB_1100x245px_2021-09-18_RZ_black"
    loading="lazy">
  <div id="logo-shadow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 #logo-container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
 }

 #logo-container img {
   width: 100%;    
  }

  #logo-shadow {
   width: 100%;
   height: 50%;
   transform: skewY(-2deg);
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0; 
   padding: 5px;
   background-color: green;
   z-index: -1;
  }
```

```html
<div id="logo-container">
  <img decoding="async" src="https://articlett.de/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/elementor/thumbs/Articlett_Logo_RGB_1100x245px_2021-09-18_RZ_black-q1r7rix22o6ztvjf52cf1pt1ojwen0jx1zyxtcyq8m.png" title="Articlett_Logo_RGB_1100x245px_2021-09-18_RZ_black" alt="Articlett_Logo_RGB_1100x245px_2021-09-18_RZ_black" loading="lazy"> 
  <div id="logo-shadow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify the css using the value `fit-content` with the `width` property of the container. This way, its size is based on the size of he biggest element which is at this point the image. Then, you can use `%` values to give a width and height to your **#logo-shadow**. You can also use relative units if you want to. Finally, you can use `rotate()` to rotate your shape.

```css
#logo-shadow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-1deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px; 
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: -1;
}

#logo-container {
  position: relative;  
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo-container">
  <img decoding="async" src="https://articlett.de/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/elementor/thumbs/Articlett_Logo_RGB_1100x245px_2021-09-18_RZ_black-q1r7rix22o6ztvjf52cf1pt1ojwen0jx1zyxtcyq8m.png" title="Articlett_Logo_RGB_1100x245px_2021-09-18_RZ_black" alt="Articlett_Logo_RGB_1100x245px_2021-09-18_RZ_black" loading="lazy"> 
  <div id="logo-shadow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it will help.